# How to place a button next to a Tab in android ? (Related to UI)

Tags: java, android, button, user-interface

I would like to place a Button next to my Tabs in my app. I've given the code below as to how I am constructing my Tabs.

This is the XML

```
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="330dp"
     >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dip"
            android:background="#000" />

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dip" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#696969" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#000" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

The code for at my Activity:

```
public class Secondactivity extends TabActivity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setupTabHost();
          mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(se.copernicus.activity.R.drawable.tab_divider);

    setupTab(new TextView(this), "Month");
    setupTab(new TextView(this), "Week");
    setupTab(new TextView(this), "Day");
    setupTab(new TextView(this), "Today");


private void setupTab(final View view, final String tag) {
View tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), tag);

TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview)
        .setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                return view;
            }
        });
mTabHost.addTab(setContent);

}

private static View createTabView(final Context context, final String text) {
View view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        .inflate(R.layout.tabs_bg, null);
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
tv.setText(text);
return view;
```

}

This my current view when I run my app

[image: Current view of APP]

What I would like to do is place a button at the place of today. How can I go about it ?

I've excluded some code that is xml that will show the pressed state as the question would get lengthy

Thank you for you input and your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

I have used the following code to generate this result. I have set the fourth tab clickable false. Only the button inside the tab will be clickable. So it would give an impression that it is not a tab. Hope this would help.

**Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {
    private TabHost mTabHost;

    private void setupTabHost() {
    mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);

    setupTabHost();
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.item_seperator);

    setupTab(new TextView(this), "Month");
    setupTab(new TextView(this), "Week");
    setupTab(new TextView(this), "Day");

    final View view = new Button(this);

    View tabview = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
        R.layout.button_tabs_bg, null);
    Button button = (Button) tabview.findViewById(R.id.tabsButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button click",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec("").setIndicator(tabview)
        .setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {

            return view;
            }
        });

    mTabHost.addTab(setContent);

    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(3).setEnabled(false);

    }

    private void setupTab(final View view, final String tag) {
    View tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), tag);

    TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview)
        .setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            return view;
            }
        });

    mTabHost.addTab(setContent);
    }

    private static View createTabView(final Context context, final String text) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        .inflate(R.layout.tabs_bg, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
    tv.setText(text);
    return view;
    }
}
```

**tab_bg_selector.xml**

```
<!-- Active tab -->
<item android:state_selected="true" android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/tablight" />
<!-- Inactive tab -->
<item android:state_selected="false" android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/tabdark" />
<!-- Pressed tab -->
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/tablight" />
<!-- Selected tab (using d-pad) -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/tablight" />
```

**tabs_bg.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tabsText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Title"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="15dip" />
```

**button_tabs_bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabsLayout" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@color/buttontab"
    android:padding="10dip" android:gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tabsButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="tabdark">#333333</color>
    <color name="tablight">#999999</color>
    <color name="buttontab">#999966</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

As `TabLayout` has to be the root node of the layout, so you can try this:
Make a `TabLayout` with 3 `Tab`s and at the place of 4th `Tab` ,you can make a custom `Button` of your own.