# Using tab as an button

Tags: android, dialog, popup, popupwindow, tabview

Is it possible to use a tab, which is dynamically added as an button?? for example when clicking on the tab insted of changing to a activity or an view, it should just popup a message in form of dialog box?

thanks in advance

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222120/how-to-place-a-button-next-to-a-tab-in-android-related-to-ui/8223336#8223336.

Comment: However, @Amy88's comments answers your question directly.

Answer (score 0):

Just fire an activity that fires off a dialog then finishes.

Comment: yeaaah that would be easy and quick but i want the background to stay behind the popup?? Beside how can you finish so it would return to the earlier activity?? I tried with finish();??

Comment: The dialog should stay up. Finish does return you to the previous Activity.

Comment: I meant the background from the previous Activity should be behind the popup??

Comment: It should be if you finish the Activity that fires the Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

try override this method:

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        tabHost.setCurrent(intPositionLastTab);
        if (tabId == dynamicTabId)) dialogBox();
    }
});
```

Comment: @user1080689 As well as ademar111190's.